# Cardinality of a set that contains duplicate sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let's assume we have a set (not a multiset), that contains three subsets

$A = \{\{a,b,b\},\{b,b,a\},\{b,a,b\}\}$

From my understanding of set theory, the three subsets are all equal to each other. So would then the cardinality of the set be one, $|A|=1 $?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I would say so, although the notation {$a,a,b$} for the ordinary set {$a,b$} is just perverse. In a sense your question is really about what that notation means for ordinary sets. It's a notation I would never choose to use since it is specifically confusing. Instead, for example, we could write {$x,a,b$} with $x$ a variable, but if or when $x=a$ we'd write that set as {$a,b$}.

Comment: I see, thank you, and excuse my notation, I've picked a and b's as an example, but numbers would've been more appropriate. A better example would've been {{1,2,2},{2,2,1},{2,1,2}}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's indeed just the set $\{\{a,b\}\}$.